# STM32F767zIT6 to PC communication via a USB cable

Tags: usb, can-bus, stm32cubeide, stm32f7

I need to connect a custom board having STM32F767zIT6 as the MCU to a window PC through a USB. The aim of the board is to filter CAN-BUS messages. The existing solution uses a CANBUS-USB adapter through one of the CAN interfaces but I have been asked to implement the USB functionality on the board since it has a USB2.0 mini-B port. I need to receive CAN messages through one of the CAN interfaces and transmit it through the USB interface to a GUI on the PC and also receive CAN formatted messages from the GUI via the USB to another CAN interface on the board. I have been playing around with the HAL_library for STM32 using STM32CubeMX but I need guidance and materials I can learn faster. If possible a similar open source implementation I can learn from.

Comment: So basically you just need a CAN driver up and running on a MCU. Just look at the various libs provided from ST and take it from there?

Comment: The CAN driver has been implemented, I need to implement the USB driver in the MCU to send the CAN messages to the PC. Most examples I am seeing gives a UART over USB but I am also looking for a way to use the USB interface directly independent of UART